# Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node' with && logical operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component whose (abbreviated) code looks like this:

```
export const TestComponent: React.SFC = props => {
  const { tabs, content } = props;
  return (
    <Tabs>
      <TabList>
        {tabs.map((x, i) => {
          const { hasError, children } = x.props;
          return (
            <Tab key={i} className={hasError ? "has-error" : ""}>
              <a>{children}
                {hasError && <i className="fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"></i>}
              </a>
            </Tab>
          );
        })}
      </TabList>
      <div className="tab-content">
        {content .map((x, i) => {
          return <TabPanel key={i}>{x.props.children}</TabPanel>;
        })}
      </div>
    </Tabs>
  );
};
```

As you can see, I'm using the logical `&&` operator to do an inline IF statement.

When one of my tabs is in error (eg. because of an input that has failed validation), it correctly renders the contents of that conditional block (an error icon).  When I attempt to type something in the input, the page blows up with the following error:

[image]

I found that if I remove the inline IF block and always render the icon, it does not error.  Why is this happening?

**UPDATE** Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z6nv0j7pn3).

Comment: If you provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) I will attempt to debug it. I do not currently see an obvious reason as to why this is happening.

Comment: Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jlm8npjl55) of what I think you are trying to do. Out of curiosity, why do you have an `<a>` element with no `href`? What is the point of that element?

Comment: @KyleRichardson Yes, I recreated it in CodeSandbox myself and I'm unable to reproduce given a simplified example.  Must be something more complex in my actual code I'll have to dig into.  ps. It's another dev's code, but an anchor with no `href` satisfies certain (Bootstrap) styles.

Comment: @KyleRichardson I just updated the ticket with my example.  I believe the problem occurs when `hasError` changes (which isn't the case in either of our examples).

Comment: I see, so you're using the `<a/>` as a css selector. Have you checked to make sure the hasError and children nested properties are being updated properly? I see they are passed down as props from a parent. Are they being updated in the parent?

Comment: @KyleRichardson A colleague helped me resolve the issue which I just posted as an answer FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the cause of my issue was FontAwesome.  The original markup for my conditional icon uses the `<i>` tag, but FontAwesome ultimately converts this to an svg.  When React goes to remove the `<i>` element from the DOM, it no longer exists and it bombs.

I solved this by wrapping the conditional contents in a `<div>`:

```
{hasError && (
    <div>
        <i className="fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg" />
    </div>
)}
```